# I am not getting the correct histogram at low X values

Tags: r, histogram

I want to make a histogram of the counts of a small set of numbers.  I used:

1. 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8
2. 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6
3. 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6

I only get the correct plot for 2) -- for both 1) and 3) the count for the categories of 2 and 3 are in correct

```
> symm <- c(2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8) 

> hist(symm)

> posskew <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6)

> hist(posskew)

> negskew <- c(2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6)

> hist(negskew)
```

I expect to get a bar going to the frequency of 1 for the category of 2 in symmetric.  Instead, my bar goes up to 3 for the categories of 2 and 3 (something similar occurs in the negatively skewed)

Comment: Sorry @MrFlick!  I searched and did not the spot the answer (or did not recognize it was the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Histograms are intended for continuous data. The `hist` functions expects that it will need to bin the data, and offers quite a few options for algorithms to compute the bins, which you can see in `?hist`.

For data like yours that is essentially discrete, a barplot is more appropriate. This will not bin values together.

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
barplot(table(symm))
barplot(table(posskew))
barplot(table(negskew))
```

[image]

`barplot` itself can cause problems, because your data isn't *actually* categorical. The distance between 3 and 5 has meaning, and that meaning is the same whether or not there are any 4s. The code I show above will put 3 right next to 5 if there aren't any 4s.

```
problem = c(2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7)
barplot(table(problem))
```

[image]

A fix is to *actually make it categorical*, converting to `factor` and specifying the levels.

[image]

```
fix = factor(problem, levels = seq(min(problem), max(problem)))
barplot(table(fix))
```

---

The other fix is to force `hist` to use the breaks you want.

```
hist(problem, breaks = seq(min(problem) - 1, max(problem)))
```

[image]

This approach would work just as well for your examples. However, notice how much *less* useful the x-axis labels are in this case. `hist` is still binning the data---each bar covers a range---we've just forced the bins to include one unique value each. But the left bar covers all data from 1 to 2 (a single `2` in the data), the next bar covers all data greater than 2 through 3 (2 `3`s in the data), etc. But just looking at the histogram, you might think the data includes a single 1 and two 2s, when in fact in contains no 1s and a single 2.

**Summary:** If your data has evenly spaced values (with some missing), and you want one bar per unique value, `barplot` is great. If your data has more unique values then you want bars, then you need to bin and `hist` is great.